# Combo box inside of list control? (Unmanaged C++)

Tags: c++, user-interface, listview, combobox, unmanaged

I'm using unmanaged C++ and I was wondering if I could embed a combo box inside a column of my List View. I have tried googling for information, however I keep finding C# articles on the subject.

It seems like the LVCOLUMN's mask can support text and images but I am not finding anything about controls.

Any ideas on the subject would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a floating combo box and position it over the selected row and column of the list control. You'll need to trap all selection related operations on the list control and show, hide, or move and update the contents of the combo box.

Answer (score 1):

You could also look at some 3rd party controls which allow this (it's not really supported in the default MS common controls). For example, the [Ultimate Grid](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/MFC/UltimateGrid_Editing.aspx) allows this sort of thing. It's not well supported, but it is open source, so if nothing else it might provide some reference for what would be involved in building it.

There are probably also other commercial vendors for these controls, but I'm not going to recommend anything in particular (you can always google/etc.).

Answer (score 1):

I was looking into this recently.  If you want it to fit into the correct space then your only option, as far as i could work out, is to create your own combo box control.  Its not difficult to do and gives good results :)